# How can I Reshape vectors of data according to their Lat/Longs to produce gridded data in R

Tags: r, vector, reshape, latitude-longitude

#Create a reproducible example

```
m_1<-seq(from = 1, to = 100, length.out = length(5000))
m_2<-seq(from = 1, to = 100, length.out = length(5000))
m_3<-seq(from = 1, to = 100, length.out = length(5000))
X<-seq(from = -10, to = -5, length.out = length(5000))
Y<-seq(from = 51, to = 55, length.out = length(5000))
df<-data.frame(m_1,m_2,m_3,X,Y)
```

I want to write the data to a netcdf file. To do this, I need the data to be in a particular format. Each timeslice in `df` (m_1,m_2,m_3) is currently a vector and I want the data to be in gridded format/or a matrix of size 450(Lat/`df$Y`) X 350(Lon/`df$X`).

I think that perhaps I have to use `reshape` or `melt` to get it into this format, but I am unsure as to how that would work. Ultimately, I want an X of length 350, a Y of length 450 and each timeslice '`m_1`' for example to be of size 350 x 450. Is this possible?
I want each of the m_1,m_2,m_3 to be like this:

```
whatiwant=array(1:100, c(450,350))
```

Comment: I think it would be a lot simpler to go with a sample that one can show simply, perhaps 5-10 instead of 5000. That way, you could show exactly how you want a 5-coordinate frame to look. ........ I guess I shouldn't really complain, though, since the _actual_ results of `length.out=length(5000)` reduces to `length.out=1` (since 5000 is a length-1 vector).

Comment: There's probably already a function and workflow for that: https://pjbartlein.github.io/REarthSysSci/netCDF.html

Comment: @I_O Not that I can see. Did you see a particular Netcdf functionality that I missed?